# Splitting a string into 2 variables... not working

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to take the event name (example: Manny Pacquiao vs. Juan Manuel Marquez) from the database, split the event name into the 2 names (Manny Pacquiao, Juan Manuel Marquez) and use them on the page.

Here is my code which is not working.

```
    if(count($perfarray) == 2 && $page['catnum'] == "1142")
    {

        $input = $event['Event'];
        $params = explode('vs.', $input);
        foreach($params as $param) 
            {
                $kv = explode('vs.', $param);
                $fighterNo1 = $kv[0];
                $fighterNo2 = $kv[1];
            }

        $fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter1", $fighterNo1, $fulltext);
        $fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter2", $fighterNo2, $fulltext);

        // $fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter1", addslashes($perfarray[0]), $fulltext);
        //$fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter2", addslashes($perfarray[1]), $fulltext);
    }
    elseif(strstr($event['Event']," vs."))
    {
        $input = $event['Event'];
        $params = explode('vs.', $input);
        foreach($params as $param) 
            {
                $kv = explode('vs.', $param);
                $fighterNo1 = $kv[0];
                $fighterNo2 = $kv[1];
            }

        $fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter1", $fighterNo1, $fulltext);
        $fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter2", $fighterNo2, $fulltext);
    }
```

Comment: The best I can get it to work is to get only one name.

Comment: Why are you exploding the `$input` twice?

Comment: I was working off a few examples to try to get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling explode too many times.

```
$params = explode('vs.', $input);
foreach($params as $param) {
   $kv = explode('vs.', $param);
```

You're taking the first parameter, and then trying to `explode` it again. This should work, I think:

```
$input = $event['Event'];
$params = explode('vs.', $input);
$fighterNo1 = $params[0];
$fighterNo2 = $params[1];

$fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter1", $fighterNo1, $fulltext);
$fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter2", $fighterNo2, $fulltext);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine!  I tried a bunch of different things based on examples I've seen but guess I used too many pieces and I should have kept it simple ;-)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
    $input = $event['Event'];
    $params = explode('vs.', $input);
    foreach($params as $param) 
        {
            $kv = explode('vs.', $param);
            $fighterNo1 = $kv[0];
            $fighterNo2 = $kv[1];
        }
```

In the second line above, you already `explode`d the `$params` right? And in the 5th line, you again `explode`ing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data looks like exactly but here is what you can do

```
$text = "Manny Pacquiao vs. Juan Manuel Marquez";

list($fighter1,$fighter2) =explode(" vs. ",$text);

$fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter1", $fighter1, $fulltext);
$fulltext = str_replace("\$Fighter2", $fighter2, $fulltext);
```